# asp.net MapPageRoute loading page twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

Not sure whats going on, but I have a rewrite with two parameters. For some reason the page is loading twice when it's called. I know that it's the rewrite because it works fine when it's just one parameter. Thanks for any help.

This is in my Global.asax

```
 routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RouteForAlbum", "album/{autoID}/{albumName}", "~/SitePages/AlbumView.aspx");
```

This is on my page load

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    string id = Page.RouteData.Values["autoID"].ToString();
    string albuname = Page.RouteData.Values["albumName"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, found the answer after more searching. If you have javascript reference with ../ this causes issues with URL rewritting. 
[asp.net Multiple Page_Load events for a user control when using URL Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614940/asp-net-multiple-page-load-events-for-a-user-control-when-using-url-routing)

Answer (score 0):

**UDPATE:**

This can also happen when using CSS3PIE together with ASP.net Routing and the two don't play nicely together.

Any CSS3PIE css styles with a URL in the value can cause the target page to execute the code behind multilple times. For me specifically, it was these two lines:

- behavior: url(PIE.htc);
- -pie-background: url(bg-image.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #53A9FF);

Changing the above two lines to start with a leading slash "/" fixed it along with specifying the whole path to the files.

- behavior: url(/scripts/PIE-1.0.0/PIE.htc);
- -pie-background: url(/scripts/PIE-1.0.0/bg-image.png) no-repeat, linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #53A9FF);

Comment: Also, a side note about using asp.net routing and unnecessary code behind execution, is that the routing also seems to run the code behind for other pages other than the one requested in some scenarios. After some trial and error, I noticed that it will not do this if your routeUrl param (2nd param on MapPageRoute) points to a different routeUrl directory than that of the requested page.